# NextJs router URL manipulation

Tags: reactjs, next.js, router

When I'm pushing to router by:

```
router.push({ query: { list: [...arr] }, { list2: [...arr2] })
```

I would like to have something like this in URL: 'list=listitem1,listitem2?list2=list2item1,list2item2,list2item3' instead of 'list=item1?list=item2?list2=list2item1?list2=list2item2' etc...

Is that even possible using router.push? If yes, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Did you try joining the array with `,`? `list: arr.join(',')`

Comment: It didn't come to my mind earlier but I've tried it now and it works, it is adding items after comma but comma ( , ) appears in the URL as %2C, question is, how can I replace '%2C' with normal comma ( , ) in the URL?

Comment: Using the URL object format to pass the query params will encode the values. Try using a string instead for the URL.